# Jquery Accordion : set action to a specific element inside header

Tags: jquery, header, click, accordion

by default, if we have something like this as a Header in jQuery Accordion :

```
<h3>
    <div class="1">TEXT</div>
    <div class="2">ICON</div>
    <div class="3">BUTTON</div>
</h3>
```

by clicking anywhere on this  , accordion works and toggle the next element and ...

the question is , how can we set an option and select a specific element ( like: 'div' with class '1' ) to click on it to and toggle the accordion.

i mean i don't want the whole Header remain click able. i just want to click on a icon or div o something inside the header and toggle open/close the accordion.

thank you

Update 1 :

HTML :

```
<div id="testAcc">

    <h3>
        <div class="one">Text</div>
        <div class="two">Icon</div>
        <div class="three">Button</div>
    </h3>
    <div class="accBody">
        text text text text text text text text text text 
    </div>

    <h3>
        <div class="one">Text</div>
        <div class="two">Icon</div>
        <div class="three">Button</div>
    </h3>
    <div class="accBody">
        text text text text text text text text text text 
    </div>

</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#testAcc').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        header: 'h3',
        collapsible: 'ture',
});
```

this codes working fine. but i want to use something like ( header: 'h3>.one' ) means i want to set a specific class and element inside the header , then if user click ONLY on that element, the accordion will open or close ...

Comment: show us the javascript so we can see what you are doing ...

Comment: html and js added. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return false` with a click handler on the elements you don't want to have the accordion toggling effect, like this:

```
$('#testAcc').accordion({
  autoHeight: false,
  header: 'h3',
  collapsible: true
});
$("#testAcc .two, #testAcc .three").click(function() {
  return false;
});
​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qE6E8/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. but if class .one , .two & .three has FLOAT , then we have some empty space remain in H3 . like this :

H3 :
<|--one--||--two--||--three--|             >

if user click on that empty space , accordion will toggle close/open.

Comment: @J.Tay - That's all CSS :) If you give `.one` a border, you'll see it takes up all that space, if you don't want it to you need to change the styling floating it or something...the jQuery side is correct, you are indeed clicking on `.one`, what width it has you need to decide :)